# "Failed To Fetch" error when trying to download a file

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm getting an intermittent error when using `files.download()`. After creating a data frame in pandas the ending to my code is:

```
#...other stuff that creates a ~50,000 row, ~8Mb CSV...
dataDf.to_csv('myFilename.csv', index=False)
files.download('myFilename.csv')
```

Running this I sometimes get the error **`MessageError: TypeError: Failed to fetch`**

Sometimes rerunning the cell again gets the download to work, other times creating another cell after the failed cell and running just `files.download('myFilename.csv')` works.

Anyone know how to stop this happening? Or know why it only happens sometimes?

I want to share this file with non-technical users so it would be really handy if they could just press the play button at the side of the first cell and have the file automatically download.